# How to reuse component with different tags using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, components, code-reuse

I have two almost identical components,
Component A:

```
const ClaimedLabel = ():React.Element => (
 <div tw="">
  <p tw="">Some Text here</p>
  <div tw="">
  <Icon src="./icon.png" />
  </div>
</div>)
```

Component B:

```
const ClaimedLabelPDF = ():React.Element => (
     <View tw="">
      <Text tw="">Some Text here</p>
      <View tw="">
      <Icon src="./icon.png" />
      </View>
    </View>)
```

tw - is tailwind style I ignored to improve code redability.
As you can see those two components are identical but diferent tags were used, is it possible to write one single component to reuse it ?
I have one idea to use isPDF flag, put two components into one and return component based on flag value, but in this case I still have duplicates:

```
const ClaimedLabel = (isPDF: boolean): React.Element => isPDF ? <View>...</View> : <div....</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just create references to the Types of elements you need to swap.

```
const ClaimedLabel = (isPDF: boolean): React.Element =>  {
  const RView = isPdf ? View : 'div';
  const RText = isPdf ? Text : 'p';
  return (
    <RView tw="">
      <RText tw="">Some Text here</p>
      <RView tw="">
      <Icon src="./icon.png" />
      </RView>
    </RView>
  );
}
```